# Java List elements multiplication without using nested loop

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multiplication

I have input Integer inputList as [1, 2, 3, 4] and want the outputList as [24, 12, 8, 6]. Logic is as follows:

```
outList[0] = inList[1]*inList[2]*inList[3]
outList[1] = inList[0]*inList[2]*inList[3]
outList[2] = inList[0]*inList[1]*inList[3]
.
.
outList[n] = inList[0]*inList[1]*...*inList[n-1]
```

Catch here is to implement this without using nested loop. I know how to do it with nested loop.
Please suggest a way to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the logic. Is `outList[n]` the multiplication of all `inList`s except `inList[n]`?

Comment: Not sum but, it's multiplication of inList elements.

Comment: Hint/Solution: Just calculate the product of all your array elements once and save that number as `totalProduct`.  The value for `outList[x]`  can then be calculated by a simple `outlist[x] = totalProduct / inList[x]`

Comment: @rexD, is input array good enough not to contain 0's or too many/too big numbers to cause integer overflow?

Comment: Input array may or may not contain 0's but, integer overflow is a valid concern. For the time being if we ignore overflow concern, then solution provided by @OHGODSPIDERS looks good. Divide by 0 can be handled.

Answer (score 0):

This method creates a new `outputArray` of length to the input array and two integer `pos` and `product`.
In the first for loop the total product of the array is found then in the next loop the variable `pos` is increased by 1, just to get the index number of the outputArray. Then using the variable pos the outputArray gets filled by dividing the total product of the array with each element of the inputArray which results in what you're looking for.
This might throw an Exception when the product is more than the maximum value that any Integer can hold.

```
 public static int[] calculateProduct(int[] array)
 {
     int[] outputArray = new int[array.length];
     int pos = -1;
     int product = 1;
    
     for(int a : array)
     {
         product *= a;
     }
    
     for(int x : array)
     {
         pos++;
         outputArray[pos] = product / x;
     }
    
     return outputArray;
 }
```